# using easyslider with asp.net to create a registration wizard

Tags: asp.net, jquery, easyslider

I am trying to make a registration wizard that contains about 6 steps.
I have moved away from using the standard asp.net registration wizard as I want more control over the look and feel.

I am using the easyslider plugin as I want a back and forward button that allows the users to click through the steps and be able to go back and forwards.

So everything was going well until a added an asp.net button into the plug. When I click it the page postback isnt happening, Does the plugin stop the ability to use asp.net controls inside? Is there something else I need to do to enable the click event to fire when using this plugin?

Any advise would be great!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your button is registered properly (eg : with a `runat="server"`) in the aspx file.

Did you try to move that button outside of your wizard ? I never used easyslider but I guess, like most sliders, it "just" hides or shows partial part of the page so I see nothing that could prevent a post back from happening.